# NodeJS Express wildcard route executed several times

Tags: node.js, express

Consider the following code snippet:

```
var count = 0;

function a(req, res, next){
   count++;
   console.log(count);
   next();
};

app.get('*', a);
app.get("/", routes.index);
app.get("/foo", routes.foo);
```

Function a() will be executed for every route defined, in this case 2, per http request.  The count variable is just to illustrate.  So if I had 100 routes defined, a() would be executed 100 times per request to the site.  Is this the expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the network traffic or log the request in your `a` function.  Most likely the second request you are seeing is for favicon.ico.  Each route when only be called once per matching request.

Comment: Nah, just slightly more informed now :)